# Aggregate rows outside the top

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, sql-server-2014

Let's say we have the following Fruits table:

```
Fruit   | Qty
-------------
Apple   | 2
Apple   | 5
Apple   | 2
Orange  | 3
Orange  | 4
Orange  | 0
Banana  | 2
Banana  | 5
Pear    | 2
Mango   | 1
Mango   | 0
```

If I want to get the top 3 fruit I would create a query like this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 Fruit, SUM(Qty) AS Total
FROM Fruits
GROUP BY Fruit
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

will return:

```
Apple   | 9
Orange  | 7
Banana  | 7
```

However, if I want to include the sum of the Fruit that ain't in the top 3, I would have to write something like this to exclude the Top 3 fruits using a `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT 'OTHER' AS Fruit, SUM(Qty) AS Total
FROM Fruits
WHERE Fruit NOT IN (SELECT Fruit FROM (SELECT TOP 3 Fruit, SUM(Qty) AS Total FROM Fruits GROUP BY Fruit ORDER BY Total DESC) AS Test)
```

If I want to execute this in a single query, I guess I could combine the 2 queries using a `UNION`.  I already have my plan B but I'm wondering if SQL has any built-in way to aggregate rows that ain't part of the top values that could be used to simplified the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to RANK the sums and add another SUM for the final result:

```
with cte as
 (
   SELECT Fruit, SUM(Qty) AS Qty,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Qty) DESC) AS rn
   FROM Fruits 
   GROUP BY Fruit
 )
select 
   case when rn > 3 then 'Other' else fruit end as fruit, 
   sum(Qty)
from cte
group by 
   case when rn > 3 then 'Other' else fruit end
order by MIN(rn)
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fc2b2/4)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it by ranking rows based on `sum(qty)`.

```
with totals as (SELECT Fruit, SUM(Qty) AS Total FROM Fruits GROUP BY Fruit)
, rownums as (select *, dense_rank() over(order by total desc) as rank from totals)
select 
case when rank > 3 then 'Other' else fruit end as fruit, total
from rownums
```

If the `other` rows need aggregation, include one more `sum` on the `total` column and `group by` the `case` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Almost!, its a shame you cant just put the RANK in a having!! but you cant. so you have to have a nested select and then a where.

Plus with this method you can get any groups you want, Ie BETWEEN 0 AND 3.. > 3 .. IN(1,3,6) etc

```
DECLARE @Fruits TABLE (Fruit NVARCHAR(32),Qty INT)
INSERT INTO @Fruits(Fruit,Qty)
VALUES
('Apple',2),
('Apple',5),
('Apple',2),
('Orange',3),
('Orange',4),
('Orange',0),
('Banana',2),
('Banana',5),
('Pear',2),
('Mango',1),
('Mango',0)

SELECT TOP 3 Fruit, SUM(Qty) AS Total
FROM @Fruits
GROUP BY Fruit
ORDER BY Total DESC

SELECT A.Fruit,A.Total FROM
(
    SELECT Fruit, SUM(Qty) AS Total,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Qty) DESC,Fruit) AS GroupNumber
    FROM @Fruits
    GROUP BY Fruit
) AS A
WHERE GroupNumber > 3 --This bit lets you pick the groups!
ORDER BY Total DESC
```